# Word document export from web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ms-word, doc

I need to export word documents from a web app. I currently use NPOI for excel export, but it doesn't seem to cover word export.
I've found Aspose Word, is there other valid alternatives?

I need to be able to use a word template document, and bookmarks should preferably be supported.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind writing some lines of code you can use [OpenXML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx). It allow you to create from scratch word, excel and powerpoint files. I used it in a project in wich the users uploaded docuemnt templates and then the app replace the bookmark with values taken from DB. The same thing with excel, but workin with cell coordinates

Comment: Ideally I would like to find something that works similar to word automation as I have already working code. Then another problem is that I would like support .doc as well. But it's definitely an option. Thank you!

Comment: I migrated from an interop use and I must say that the learning curve for tha xml part is a little tricky but with the document explorer is done relatively fast. You can find also some code on the web (I'm writing a post on this too). But what I found a deal breaker was that I have to not insatlla word on the server and with only a dll all is done

Answer (score 1):

for exporting word documents from a web app, Spire.Doc may useful for you, doc and docx supported.